# When I use *ngSwitch in a Bootstrap navbar the styling disappears

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, navbar, ng-switch

```
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                <li class='nav-item'>
                    <ul [ngSwitch]='isLoggedIn' class='nav-item'>
                      <li *ngSwitchCase=true>
                        <a routerLink='/home' id='home' class='nav-item'>Home</a>
                      </li>
                      <li *ngSwitchCase=false>
                        <a routerLink='/login' id='home' class='nav-item'>Home</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
.
.
.
.
```

The link changes as it's supposed to when isLoggedIn is toggled, but with this setup there is no Bootstrap styling on the link itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `ngSwitch` when you only have 2 cases? Looks like an overkill.
More importantly, you've got a `ul.nav` inside of another `ul.nav`... Why not go with this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
    <a routerLink="/home" id="home" class="nav-item">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
    <a routerLink="/login" id="login" class="nav-item">Login</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are wrong for overkill!! 

For *ngIf, every condition will be checked and the code inside the true condition will be executed.

For [ngSwitch], only the code inside the specific case will be executed (using break;).

So, [ngSwitch] will be faster.

Comment: `Every view that matches is rendered.` -- https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch#description How does the walker know which view matches? A condition is checked :) But anyways, I still stand by what I wrote -- `ngSwitch` should not be used here.